Issue with multiprocessing and Pulse Width Modulation on Raspberry Pi
It seems to me that I have problems running pwm in multiprocessing, and I wonder if you have any ideas on how to resolve this.
I have a project where I'm building a toy car being controlled by a Raspberry Pi 4. I've been running everything as threads until I've now tried experimenting with multiprocessing to better utilize the CPU. Anyhow, most of the program works like before except for the parts that use PWM. The parts that just use GPIO.HIGH and GPIO.LOW or pigpio works just like before.
The motors and lights which are set up with PWM are not responding, though I can see that the code is being run without errors.
Ignore any references to threads in the code, as that is me not having bothered to clean up old names and comments seeing as this is still just an experiment to see if I can get it run as several processes instead.
main.py - the main file of the program
from CarHandling import CarHandling
from ArduinoCommunicator import ArduinoCommunicator, InvalidPortError
from Camera import Camera
from CameraHelper import CameraHelper
from ServoHandling import ServoHandling
from carControl import CarControl, X11ForwardingError
from xboxControl import NoControllerDetected
from roboCarHelper import print_startup_error
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# define GPIO pins
rightForward = 22 # IN2 
rightBackward = 18 # IN1
leftForward = 16 # IN4
leftBackward = 15 # IN3
enA = 11
enB = 13

servoPin = 26 # BCM

buzzerPin = 29

lightPin1 = 36
lightPin2 = 31

# set GPIO layout
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# set up car controller
try:
    carController = CarControl()
except (X11ForwardingError, NoControllerDetected) as e:
    print_startup_error(e)
    exit()

# define distance warning system for car
port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baudrate = 115200 # the highest communication rate between a pi and an arduino

try:
    arduinoCommunicator = ArduinoCommunicator(port, baudrate)
    arduinoCommunicator.activate_distance_sensors(buzzerPin)
    arduinoCommunicator.activate_photocell_lights([lightPin1, lightPin2])
except InvalidPortError as e:
    print_startup_error(e)
    exit()

# define car handling
car = CarHandling(leftBackward, leftForward, rightBackward, rightForward, enA, enB)

# define servo aboard car
servo = ServoHandling(servoPin)

# define camera aboard car
resolution = (384, 288)
cameraHelper = CameraHelper()
camera = Camera(resolution, cameraHelper)
cameraHelper.add_car(car)
cameraHelper.add_servo(servo)

# add components
carController.add_car(car)
carController.add_servo(servo)
carController.add_arduino_communicator(arduinoCommunicator)

# activate distance warning, camera and car controlling
#myEvent = Event()
carController.enable_camera(cameraHelper)
carController.activate_arduino_communication()
carController.activate_car_handling()

flag = carController.shared_flag

# keep process running until keyboard interrupt
try:
    while not flag.value: # listen for any threads setting the event
        # camera module will be run from main module, since cv2 is not thread safe
        camera.show_camera_feed(carController.shared_dict)
    print("Exiting camera")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    flag.value = True # set event to stop all active processes
finally:
    carController.cleanup() # cleanup to finish all threads and close processes
    camera.cleanup()
    GPIO.cleanup()

carControl.py - class that basically controls all functionality on the car
import subprocess
#from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Value
from xboxControl import XboxControl

class CarControl:
    def __init__(self):
        if not self._check_if_X11_connected():
            raise X11ForwardingError("X11 forwarding not detected.")

        self._xboxControl = XboxControl()

        self._car = None
        self._servo = None
        self._arduinoCommunicator = None

        self._cameraEnabled = False
        self._cameraHelper = None

        self._threads = []
        self._threadLock = None

        self._buttonToObjectDict = {
        }
        self.shared_dict = Array('i', (0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.shared_flag = Value('b', False)

    def add_arduino_communicator(self, arduinoCommunicator):
        self._arduinoCommunicator = arduinoCommunicator

    def add_car(self, car):
        self._car = car

    def enable_camera(self, cameraHelper):
        self._cameraEnabled = True
        self._cameraHelper = cameraHelper

    def add_servo(self, servo):
        self._servo = servo

    def activate_arduino_communication(self):
        thread = Process(target=self._listen_for_arduino_communication, args=(self.shared_flag,))
        self._threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    def activate_car_handling(self):
        thread = Process(target=self._start_car_handling, args=(self.shared_flag,))
        self._threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    def cleanup(self):
        # close all threads
        for thread in self._threads:
            thread.join()

        if self._car:
            self._car.cleanup()

        if self._servo:
            self._servo.cleanup()

        if self._arduinoCommunicator:
            self._arduinoCommunicator.cleanup()

    def _start_car_handling(self, flag):
        self._print_button_explanation()
        self._map_all_objects_to_buttons()

        while not flag.value:
            for event in self._xboxControl.get_controller_events():
                button, pressValue = self._xboxControl.get_button_and_press_value_from_event(event)
                if self._xboxControl.check_for_exit_event(button):
                    self._exit_program(flag)
                    break

                # get the object to take action based on the button pushed
                try:
                    self._buttonToObjectDict[button].handle_xbox_input(button, pressValue)
                except KeyError: # if key does not correspond to object, then go to next event
                    continue

                if self._cameraEnabled:
                    self._cameraHelper.update_control_values_for_video_feed(self.shared_dict)
        print("Exiting car handling")

    def _print_button_explanation(self):
        print()
        print("Controller layout: ")
        if self._car:
            print("Car controls:")
            print("Turn left: " + self._car.car_buttons()["Left"])
            print("Turn right: " + self._car.car_buttons()["Right"])
            print("Drive forward: " + self._car.car_buttons()["Gas"])
            print("Reverse: " + self._car.car_buttons()["Reverse"])
            print()
        if self._servo:
            print("Servo controls:")
            print("Turn servo: " + self._servo.servo_buttons()["Servo"])
            print()
        if self._cameraEnabled:
            print("Camera controls")
            print("Zoom camera: " + self._cameraHelper.camera_buttons()["Zoom"])
            print("Turn HUD on or off: " + self._cameraHelper.camera_buttons()["HUD"])
            print()

        print(f"Double tap {self._xboxControl.get_exit_button()} to exit")

    def _map_all_objects_to_buttons(self):
        if self._car:
            self._add_object_to_buttons(self._car.car_buttons(), self._car)

        if self._servo:
            self._add_object_to_buttons(self._servo.servo_buttons(), self._servo)

        if self._cameraEnabled:
            self._add_object_to_buttons(self._cameraHelper.camera_buttons(), self._cameraHelper)

    def _add_object_to_buttons(self, buttonDict, roboObject):
        for button in list(buttonDict.values()):
            self._buttonToObjectDict[button] = roboObject

    def _listen_for_arduino_communication(self, flag):
        while not flag.value:
            self._arduinoCommunicator.start()
        print("Exiting arduino")


    def _exit_program(self, flag):
        flag.value = True
        print("Exiting program...")

    def _check_if_X11_connected(self):
        result = subprocess.run(["xset", "q"], capture_output=True, text=True)
        returnCode = result.returncode

        if not returnCode:
            print("Succesful connection to forwarded X11 server")

        return not returnCode


class X11ForwardingError(Exception):
    pass

CarHandling.py - this controls the car
I can see that this code is being called and run, but it's not actually moving the motors since I switched from threading to multiprocessing.
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from roboCarHelper import map_value_to_new_scale
from itertools import chain

class CarHandling:
    def __init__(self, leftBackward, leftForward, rightBackward, rightForward, enA, enB):
        self._leftBackward = leftBackward
        self._leftForward = leftForward
        self._rightBackward = rightBackward
        self._rightForward = rightForward
        self._enA = enA
        self._enB = enB

        self._pwmMinTT = 20 # this needs to be set to the value where the motors start "biting"
        self._pwmMaxTT = 60

        self._speed = 0

        self._turnLeft = False
        self._turnRight = False

        self._goForward = False
        self._goReverse = False

        self._gpioThrottle = {True: GPIO.HIGH, False: GPIO.LOW}

        GPIO.setup(leftBackward, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(leftForward, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(rightBackward, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(rightForward, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(enA, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(enB, GPIO.OUT)

        self._pwmA = GPIO.PWM(enA, 100)
        self._pwmB = GPIO.PWM(enB, 100)

        self._pwmA.start(0)
        self._pwmB.start(0)

        self._controlsDictTurnButtons = {
            "Left": "D-PAD left",
            "Right": "D-PAD right",
        }

        self._controlsDictThrottle = {
            "Gas": "RT",
            "Reverse": "LT"
        }

        self._turnButtons = list(self._controlsDictTurnButtons.values())

        self._gasAndReverseButtons = list(self._controlsDictThrottle.values())

    def handle_xbox_input(self, button, pressValue):
        if button in self._turnButtons:
            self._prepare_car_for_turning(button, pressValue)
            self._move_car()
        elif button in self._gasAndReverseButtons:
            self._prepare_car_for_throttle(button, pressValue)
            self._move_car()

    def car_buttons(self):
        completeDict = dict(chain(self._controlsDictThrottle.items(), self._controlsDictTurnButtons.items()))

        return completeDict

    def get_current_speed(self):
        return int(self._speed)

    def get_current_turn_value(self):
        if self._turnLeft:
            return "Left"
        elif self._turnRight:
            return "Right"
        else:
            return "-"

    def _change_duty_cycle(self, pwms, speed):
        for pwm in pwms:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)

    def _adjust_gpio_values(self, gpioValues):
        leftForwardValue, rightForwardValue, leftBackwardValue, rightBackwardValue = gpioValues

        GPIO.output(self._leftForward, self._gpioThrottle[leftForwardValue])
        GPIO.output(self._rightForward, self._gpioThrottle[rightForwardValue])
        GPIO.output(self._leftBackward, self._gpioThrottle[leftBackwardValue])
        GPIO.output(self._rightBackward, self._gpioThrottle[rightBackwardValue])

    def _move_car(self):
        if self._goForward:
            if not self._turnLeft and not self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [True, True, False, False]
            elif self._turnLeft:
                gpioValues = [False, True, False, False]
            elif self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [True, False, False, False]
        elif self._goReverse:
            if not self._turnLeft and not self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [False, False, True, True]
            elif self._turnLeft:
                gpioValues = [False, False, False, True]
            elif self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [False, False, True, False]
        elif not self._goReverse and not self._goForward:
            if not self._turnLeft and not self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [False, False, False, False]
            elif self._turnLeft:
                gpioValues = [False, True, True, False]
            elif self._turnRight:
                gpioValues = [True, False, False, True]

        self._adjust_gpio_values(gpioValues)

    def _prepare_car_for_turning(self, button, buttonState):
        stopTurning = False

        if button == "D-PAD left" and buttonState == 1:
            self._turnLeft = True
            self._turnRight = False
        elif button == "D-PAD right" and buttonState == 1:
            self._turnLeft = False
            self._turnRight = True
        else:
            self._turnLeft = False
            self._turnRight = False
            stopTurning = True

        if not stopTurning:
            if not self._goForward and not self._goReverse:
                self._change_duty_cycle([self._pwmA, self._pwmB], self._pwmMaxTT)

    def _prepare_car_for_throttle(self, button, buttonPressValue):
        speed = map_value_to_new_scale(
            buttonPressValue,
            self._pwmMinTT,
            self._pwmMaxTT,
            2
        )
        if speed > self._pwmMinTT + 1: # only change speed if over the treshold
            if button == "RT":
                self._goForward = True
                self._goReverse = False
            elif button == "LT":
                self._goForward = False
                self._goReverse = True
        else:
            speed = 0

            self._goForward = False
            self._goReverse = False

        self._change_duty_cycle([self._pwmA, self._pwmB], speed)
        self._speed = speed

    def cleanup(self):
        self._pwmA.stop()
        self._pwmB.stop()

The rest of the code files are here, if it's of any interest: https://github.com/Siggerud/roboCar/tree/multiProcess2/src
I've seen someone have a similar problem on this forum, but no real clues on how to fix it.
Issues with multiprocessing and motor power with Raspberry Pi 4B
Sorry for superlong post. All tips greatly appreciated.

Taking a guess here: As processes are completely separate entities there might be an issue with the hardware access to GPIO. You are loading this module in your main-process and in the sub module CarHandling. I don't know how GPIO is written but I would assume it allows only single access. Maybe try that in a little test program.

By using Threads the access to the hardware might be protected by the GIL which isn't there with Processes so race conditions aren't excluded and the GPIO module could prohibit that.

You are right. I tried loading the GPIO module in each process instead, and that got the PWMs working again.
